# Can I allow multiple domains on one FB app?

Tags: facebook

It appears that there has been an update to only allow domains whose url is either the website, Facebook app canvas, or Facebook tab urls. It was previously recommended that we add multiple domains for multiple sites that we wanted to use a particular Facebook app on.

If now I simply make no changes and save the settings for the Facebook app, I get an error saying

> This must be derived from Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Site URL,
>   Mobile Site URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and
>   correct the following domains: mydomain.com

This leads to the fact that you can only have 3 domains total per Facebook app, and that in order to have multiple domains you need to have a platform added that you may or may not want.

What is the current best practice on Facebook to allow multiple domains for the same Facebook app?